# "OK" button not showing properly in MaterialDatePicker

Tags: android, material-design

[image]

"OK" Button not showing in MaterialDatePicker

```
MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
   @Override
   public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {

   }
});
picker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

Comment: Post your app theme

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?